# how to parse a csv from an auto download url using php

Tags: php, csv, curl

I have a product feed which automatically downloads as a csv when I put the url in a browser.

I want to write a php script to get the data from the url,parse it,get what data I require and create a new csv.

The problem i am facing is when I use curl or `file_get_contents()` I get an empty array.

Update:

the new CSV file is empty

```
$feed = 'https:/www.url/feeds/feed.csv';
   $path = "./newfile.csv";
   function download_page($path,$feed){
   $fp = fopen ($path, 'w+');
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$feed);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
   $retValue = curl_exec($ch);           
   curl_close($ch);
   fclose($fp);
   return $retValue;
}
```

Comment: We need to see code.

Comment: There might be some Javascript involved on the web page to start the download.

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_FILE` changes the output from `STDOUT` to a file, but then `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` tells it not to output anything. Use one or the other:

```
  function download_page($path,$feed){
      $ch = curl_init($feed);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
      $retValue = curl_exec($ch);   
      curl_close($ch);
      if($retValue === false) {
          return false;
      } else {
          file_put_contents($path, $retValue);
          return true;
      }
  }

  $feed = 'https:/www.url/feeds/feed.csv';
  $path = "./newfile.csv";
  download_page($path,$feed);
```

Incidentally, this could be done with [much less code](http://php.net/file-get-contents), though you may have less flexibility to catch 404 errors and whatnot:

```
function download_page($path,$feed)
{
    $result = file_get_contents($feed);
    return $result ? file_put_contents($path, $result) : false;
}
```

Comment: nothing came through when i tried both th snippets you suggested I got this warning Warning: file_get_contents(https:url/feeds/feed.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: That would suggest the URL is not found. What is the URL?

Comment: its a client feed so cannot share it here can i pm it to u?

Comment: No such thing as far as I know. If it's HTTPS, does it have a valid certificate? Is it accessible if you just do a `curl` from command line of the server? Could be some reason the server can't reach it, or server could be blocking bots based on user agent. Any number of things.